# Параллельное сжатие данных

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Помогите разобраться в чём проблема.
Необходимо поблочно (1МБ примерно) считывать данные из файла, сжимать их GZipом и записывать в выходной файл. Сжатие должно быть реализовано в нескольких потоках в зависимости от количества ядер в системе. Файл больше размера оперативной памяти.
Для решения проблемы я реализовал паттерн producer-consumer. И разбиваю сжатие на несколько потоков. Чтение файла, сжатие и запись проходят хорошо в конечном итоге приложение зависает и ожидает данные на запись из очереди в выходной файл. Что я делаю не так и правильно ли такая организация?

Вот рабочий пример:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MultiThreadGZip
{
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public class Block
    {
        private int id;
        private byte[] buffer;
        private byte[] compressedBuffer;

        public int ID { get { return id; } }
        public byte[] Buffer { get { return buffer; } }
        public byte[] CompressedBuffer { get { return compressedBuffer; } }

        public Block(int id, byte[] buffer) : this(id, buffer, new byte[0]) { }

        public Block(int id, byte[] buffer, byte[] compressedBuffer)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.buffer = buffer;
            this.compressedBuffer = compressedBuffer;
        }
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public sealed class QueueHandler
    {
        private object locker = new object();
        private Queue<Block> queue = new Queue<Block>();
        private bool stop = false;
        private int id = 0;

        public void StopProcess()
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                stop = true;
                Monitor.PulseAll(locker);
            }
        }

        public void Enqueue(Block block)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                if (stop)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Очередь остановлена!");

                while (id != block.ID)
                    Monitor.Wait(locker);

                queue.Enqueue(block);
                id++;
                Monitor.PulseAll(locker);
            }
        }

        public Block Dequeue()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                lock (locker)
                {
                    while (queue.Count == 0 && !stop)
                        Monitor.Wait(locker);

                    if (queue.Count == 0)
                        return null;

                    return queue.Dequeue();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    class Program
    {
        QueueHandler reader = new QueueHandler();
        QueueHandler writer = new QueueHandler();
        static int threadsCount = Environment.ProcessorCount;
        Thread[] workersThreds = new Thread[threadsCount];
        int blockSize = 1048576;
        int counterOperation = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program().Run();
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            var read = new Thread(Read); // Чтение файла
            read.Start();

            for (int i = 0; i < threadsCount; i++)
            {
                workersThreds[i] = new Thread(Compress);
                workersThreds[i].Start();
            }

            var write = new Thread(Write); // Запись в файл
            write.Start();
        }

            var write = new Thread(Write); // Запись в файл
            write.Start();

            WaitHandle.WaitAll(doneEvents);
        }

        public void Read()
        {
            try
            {
                using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("in1.zip", FileMode.Open))
                {
                    int bytesRead;
                    byte[] bufferRead;
                    Block block;

                    while ((fileStream.Position < fileStream.Length))
                    {
                        if (fileStream.Length - fileStream.Position <= blockSize)
                        {
                            bytesRead = (int)(fileStream.Length - fileStream.Position);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            bytesRead = blockSize;
                        }

                        bufferRead = new byte[bytesRead];
                        fileStream.Read(bufferRead, 0, bytesRead);
                        block = new Block(counterOperation, bufferRead);
                        reader.Enqueue(block);
                        ++counterOperation;
                    }

                    reader.StopProcess();
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch (IOException err)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
            }
        }

        private void Compress()
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] dataCompress;

                while (true)
                {
                    Block block = reader.Dequeue();

                    if (block != null)
                    {
                        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            using (GZipStream gz = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
                            {
                                gz.Write(block.Buffer, 0, block.Buffer.Length);
                            }

                            dataCompress = memoryStream.ToArray();
                            Block outData = new Block(block.ID, dataCompress);
                            writer.Enqueue(outData);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                return;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Компрессор: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public void Write()
        {
            try
            {
                Block block;
                using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("out.gz", FileMode.Create))
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        block = writer.Dequeue();

                        if (block == null)
                            break;

                        BitConverter.GetBytes(block.Buffer.Length).CopyTo(block.Buffer, 4);
                        fileStream.Write(block.Buffer, 0, block.Buffer.Length);
                        fileStream.Flush();
                    }
                }

                return;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Write: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100524/discussion-on-question-by-denis---).

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю можно сделать так. Добавьте в `QueueHandler` событие `Stopped`, вызывайте его перед тем как вернуть null в `Dequeue()`.

```
public event EventHandler Stopped;
private void OnStopped() => Stopped?.Invoke();
public Block Dequeue()
{
    while (true)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            while (queue.Count == 0 && !stop)
                Monitor.Wait(locker);

            if (queue.Count == 0)
            {
                OnStopped();
                return null;
            }
            return queue.Dequeue();
        }
    }
}
```

Подпишитесь на событие `reader.Stopped`, и там в обработчике вызывайте `writer.StopProcess()`

```
reader.Stopped += (s,e) => writer.StopProcess();
```